# Check CPU percentage of computing node used

Tags: linux, hpc

How can I can the CPU percentage used of each node when say job **J** is submitted to queue **Q**?

I don't want it specific to a queue which qstat gives, but specific to a job.

Comment: Are you using Torque?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Torque/Moab you should be able to use the [checkjob](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/8-1-1/basic/MWM/help.htm#topics/moabWorkloadManager/topics/moabCommands/commands/checkjob.html)(documentation linked) command to get more detailed information about the job you are interested in.  Something like:

```
checkjob -v exact:J -n <Insert Node ID here>
```

Should work to get you more information about the job, the -v, -n and Node ID are optional.

Alternately if you know the node ID/name you can use the [checknode](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/8-1-1/basic/MWM/help.htm#topics/moabWorkloadManager/topics/moabCommands/commands/checknode.html%3FTocPath%3D3%2520Scheduler%2520Commands%7CCommands%7C_____2) command and associated options to get more information about the node the job is being run on.  Hopefully that helps.